# Ant-design autocomplete ValueType/OptionType issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm trying to use antd AutoComplete with typscript with value as a string, but I'm ending up with typescript errors for both options and value.

For the **value** I have - *Type `string` is not assignable to type `ValueType | null`*

For the **options** - *Type `string[]` is not assignable to type `OptionType[]`*

However antd doesn't distrubute any `ValueType` of `OptionType` types for me to import, so I can't even guess the format that I should be using. Have anyone had or maybe solved the same issue?

```
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { AutoComplete } from 'antd';

export const TagsAutocomplete = ({onSelect, value}: {onSelect: (elem: string) => void, value: string}) => {
  const options: string[] = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3'];
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const filteredOptions = useMemo(() => {
    return options.filter((option) => option.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLowerCase()));
  }, [options, inputText]);

  return (
    <AutoComplete
      value={value} // Type string is not assignable to type ValueType | null 
      options={filteredOptions} // Type string[] is not assignable to type OptionType[]
      onSelect={onSelect}
      onSearch={setInputText}
    />
  )
}
```

For value/option format I tried to use `string` and object in format `{value: string}`. Both approaches gave me the types error

Answer (score 1):

You can check the definitions by clicking on the `options` prop while holding `ctrl` for windows/linux and `command` for Mac.

Otherwise, refer to the official [documentation](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete#api):

```
options Select options. Will get better perf than jsx definition    { label, value }[]
```

Thus, refactor `options` to `{label: string, value: string}[]` and extract it from the component, since it is a constant and no need to keep it in the component:

```
const options = [
  { label: 'Tag 1', value: 'Tag1' },
  { label: 'Tag 2', value: 'Tag2' },
  { label: 'Tag 3', value: 'Tag3' },
];
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgLJIgTZFIDKMKMScAvnAGZQQhwDkUqGHgG4AUKEixccAIL4YEAMJcwAGySMW7Ttx4oAdjAAmwkSLQQ9heBDAxgFwnAC8cANoi4UlSgBGSFQBcvAAqKADmcACMPNgAbigq+EhBPKFh0SyYHl6+-ilpcABMMXDxickh4cWZ2XjefoGVEQDMJWVJ+eGtNQC6oiJIAB4S8OaW8GmEsvLm4GoaLgAUONkWNP5IGFme7UhZzEErnmsbGEGLGyBBVlDAemEAlM4AfKUQwIaiOwkdcDd3YVEzCeTleRzgYysbjuYDkwSGWD+6gAknpYTB4YMYD1nARiHQGEhFjweA8vhCHPA2MAVIx+IYAPK2eyWXHUMgURaLEFg7KefgwfBQPRwGx2BwAOmptKQUC5YpZPNFzIsEt2EvkABkIAB3WUKFDEbkSu5oRKGJCERYwuEIjUQbV6qAGo0PN3k5jYVw2jEInpk0z89RCkWLPlwAA800UynmSHD33KThwu1YCeV4ssyeldKQjJVlmY6ZOagwyZLmxgRc8NdFenWKCgaAAFsniDBUejMVXwwB6Z7ZAPMURAA)

Comment: Unfortunately the same error
`Type {label: string, value: string}[] is not assignable to type OptionType[] `

Comment: which version of antd are you using? Can you provide a playground link?

Comment: antd: 5.6.1, typescript: 5.1.3, react: 18.2.0. Unfortunately I'm doing it locally

Comment: well, create a sandbox or something like that. Otherwise, I'm not sure how I can help you, since there is no error in the playground. Also,  when you click on the options by holding ctrl/command can you find the type definition of it? What is it?

Comment: It sends me to `SelectProps` generic interface with `OptionType` as generic arguement in *rc-select/lib/Select.d.ts.*

Comment: What are `BaseOptionType` and `DefaultOptionType` in that file?

Comment: `interface BaseOptionType { disabled?: boolean; [name: string]: any; }`
`interface DefaultOptionType extends BaseOptionType { label: React.ReactNode; value?: string | number | null; children?: Omit<DefaultOptionType, 'children'>[]; }`

However switching to format of `{label: string, value: string}` with this options from `DefaultOptionType` doesn't help much. Just tried to change label type to `React.ReactNode` like in `DefaultOptionType`, but still have *Type {label: React.ReactNode, value: string}[] is not assignable to type OptionType[]*

Comment: what are the other props that are used? Please, add a playground link with the whole component, removing irrelevant things

Comment: For some reason it doesn't reproduce in playground, only localy. And even locally component still work, but these errors are still being shown. Maybe some issue with IDE. I thumbed up your answer as it actually ads more to my code, however maybe there's someone who also stucked into this problem could solve it. At least there will be a thread about this problem, cause I haven't met this one while googling it

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Try to delete node_modules and run npm ci